# QWinTaskbarProgress won't show

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5, qtwinextras

I'm using windows7 and Qt5.3.0
I added below to my MainWindow's constructor but nothing shows on my taskbar. Did I miss something?

```
QWinTaskbarProgress * pTaskbarProgress = new QWinTaskbarProgress(this);
pTaskbarProgress->setMinimum(0);
pTaskbarProgress->setMaximum(100);
pTaskbarProgress->setValue(50);
pTaskbarProgress->show();
```

Comment: did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [example in the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwintaskbarbutton.html):

```
QWinTaskbarButton *button = new QWinTaskbarButton(widget);
button->setWindow(widget->windowHandle());
button->setOverlayIcon(QIcon(":/loading.png"));

QWinTaskbarProgress *progress = button->progress();
progress->setVisible(true);
progress->setValue(50);
```

Seems to me like you have to set this as part of a QWinTaskbarButton.

Comment: That really should be included in [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwintaskbarprogress.html).

Answer (score 12):

In fact, it seems like calling

```
button->setWindow(widget->windowHandle());
```

in QMainWindow constructor doesn't work and QWinTaskbarProgress won't show at all even after calling `setVisible(true)` or `show()`.

If created in the QMainWindow constructor it has to be called once the Window is shown like in:

```
void MainWindow::showEvent(QShowEvent *e)
{
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32
    m_button->setWindow(windowHandle());
#endif

    e->accept();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `QMainWindow constructor doesn't work` this is the correct answer for me!

Answer (score 3):

The history behind this class is that it was part of `QWinTaskbarButton`, thus it was inherently tightly coupled with that class. You can see the relevant upstream  commit that began the refactoring and hence decoupling:

[Refactor QWinTaskbarProgress out of QWinTaskbarButton](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/63791/)

You are right that it is not too explicit in QWinTaskbarProgress' documentation, so this could be potentially improved upstream, but the [QWinTaskbarButton example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwintaskbarbutton.html#details) as well as the [Music Player example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwinextras-musicplayer-example.html#taskbar-overlay-and-progress) shows the point, namely you have to replace this line:

```
QWinTaskbarProgress * pTaskbarProgress = new QWinTaskbarProgress(this);
```

with:

```
QWinTaskbarButton * pTaskbarButton = new QWinTaskbarButton(this);
pTaskbarButton->setWindow(windowHandle());
QWinTaskbarProgress * pTaskbarProgress = pTaskbarButton->progress();
```

You may wish to set the overlay icon as well for the taskbar button with either a custom image or something like what the Music Player examples does:

```
pTaskbarButton->setOverlayIcon(style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MediaPlay));
```