# What am I doing wrong with QWinTaskbarProgress?

Tags: c++, qt, qtwinextras

I followed the examples I found to make use of the `QWinTaskbarProgress`. I created a standard `Qt Widgets Application` in `Qt Creator` (Qt 5.3.1) and my `mainwindow.cpp` looks like this:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    m_taskbarButton = new QWinTaskbarButton(this);
    m_taskbarButton->setWindow(windowHandle());
    m_taskbarButton->setOverlayIcon(style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MediaPlay));

    m_taskbarProgress = m_taskbarButton->progress();
    m_taskbarProgress->setVisible(true);
    m_taskbarProgress->setRange(0, 100);
    m_taskbarProgress->setValue(50);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I expected the task bar icon to be overlaid and showing `50%` progress bar after starting the application, but the task bar looks normal, just as if did not code anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [QWinTaskbarProgress won't show](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840941/qwintaskbarprogress-wont-show)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact, it seems like calling "m_taskbarButton->setWindow(windowHandle());" in QMainWindow constructor doesn't work and QWinTaskbarProgress won't show at all even after calling setVisible(true) or show().

It has to be called once the Window is shown like in :

```
void MainWindow::showEvent(QShowEvent *e)
{
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32
    m_taskbarButton->setWindow(windowHandle());
#endif

    e->accept();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, since you put it in this define, does it behave differently on non-Windows systems then? Could we call it a bug, then?

Comment: You're welcome :) Yes, I suspect it's a bug because a QWindow should be identical in shown or hidden state :( Btw the #ifdef is because QWinTaskbarButton only exists under Windows (it's a QtWinExtras library).

Comment: Still a workaround, but I like it more than others. Sorry about my question on the define, I must have been quite tired when I asked that ;-)

Comment: `Q_OS_WIN` is a better macro, since it works on both 32 and 64-bit systems. Also, do you have to call setWindow() on every single showEvent? Calling it once is not enough?

Comment: Yes, I agree the name is perhaps better. But Q_OS_WIN32 and Q_OS_WIN64 are both defined in 64 bits as well as Q_OS_WIN.

Comment: Yes, this solution works. If even this does not work for you though, you might need to call `m_taskbarButton->progress()->show()` AFTER the window handle is set.

Answer (score 0):

Your and my code very similar to example in `Qt Documentation`. I have no idea why, but this doesn't work on my computer too. But I found solution:

Create `singleShot` and set progress in slot:

In header:

```
private slots:    
    void echo();
```

In constructor:

```
QTimer::singleShot(1000,this,SLOT(echo()));
QTimer::singleShot(10,this,SLOT(echo()));//works too
```

Slot:

```
void MainWindow::echo()
{

    QWinTaskbarButton *button = new QWinTaskbarButton(this);
    button->setWindow(windowHandle());
    button->setOverlayIcon(style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MediaPlay));

    QWinTaskbarProgress *progress = button->progress();
    progress->setVisible(true);
    progress->setRange(0, 100);
    progress->setValue(50);
}
```

And now it works!

Comment: This is just a workaround, @Kervala 's answer is the real solution.